# C# convertir Control a UIElement

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-forms, wpf

¿Como puedo convertir un `Control` a `UIElement` en Windows forms con [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)?

Estoy extrayenado los Controles de un `FlowLayoutPanel` con `Controls` pero quiero convertirlos a `UIElement`

Comment: que fue lo que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Este es un clásico ejemplo del [problema XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) Por favor dínos que es lo que quieres hacer, en lugar de preguntar lo que estás intentando, que no tiene mucho sentido ya que estás mezclando Winforms con WPF.

Comment: Mm estas en WPF o en Windows Forms? estás importando los controles de Forms a WPF? por favor complementa tu pregunta, como esta ahora mismo no  es nada clara.

Comment: Perdón si desconozco peo solo he trabajado con wpf y hay algunas cosas del api son iguales, y otras que no como esta que no son compatibles

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creo que estas mezclando [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) con [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) y esto no es posible. (si puedes utilizar `UserControls` hechos en [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf)), pero convertir un `Control` a `UIElement` no es posible.

`UIElement` deriva de otras clases

```
System.Object
  System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject
    System.Windows.DependencyObject
      System.Windows.Media.Visual
        System.Windows.UIElement
```

[Ver en MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.uielement(v=vs.110).aspx)

Mientras que `Control`

```
System.Object
  System.MarshalByRefObject
    System.ComponentModel.Component
      System.Windows.Forms.Control
```

[Ver en MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx)

Creo que el casteo o conversión no va a ser posible, deberías replantearte porque quieres convertirlo a `UIElement` en un [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms).

Answer (score 3):

No puedes convertir un control de  `Windows Forms` a `UIElement`, porque son objetos que pertenecen a jerarquías muy diferentes.

si quieres usar un control de `Windows Forms` en `WPF` deberás hacer uso de un control `WindowsFormsHost`

```
<Window x:Class="HostingWfInWpf.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"  
    Title="HostingWfInWpf"
    >

    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <wf:MaskedTextBox x:Name="mtbDate" Mask="00/00/0000"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Para poderlo usar así no olvides agregar una referencia a `WindowsFormsIntegration.dll`

Tambien puedes hacerlo por código

```
private void LoadWFUserControl() 
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
        new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
    MyFormscontrol uc_myControl= new MyFormscontrol ();
    host.Child = uc_myControl;
    this.grid1.Children.Add(host);
}
```